# R elapsed time greater than sum of system and user when loading Rda

Tags: r, performance

My R is loading Rdas very slowly, in the following unique way. I have a file with 220,000 rows and 250 columns (mostly numeric) with a total size of 40MB.

```
system.time(load("Z:/gn/data/panel220K.Rdata"))
```

reports back that the time to load was

```
user  system elapsed 
4.21    0.19  365.55
```

My friend loaded the same file on a similar machine (we both have Windows 7 Enterpise with Intel Core i7, using RStudio) and it took 30 seconds.

(1) Why might it be taking mine so much longer to load?
(2) Why is time elapsed so much larger than the sum of user time and system time?

Thanks!

Comment: I would expect it to be disk access delays, which is not cpu bound.

Comment: Z-disk is mapped network drive?

Comment: Bingo. @James Sounds like I should copy the file locally. Thanks!